# Group of order $n=pq$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let be $G$ a group of order $n=pq$, where $p$ and $q$ are prime numbers.

1. Let be $x\in$ G and $x\neq$ e, determine possible values of order of $x$.
2. Deduct that $G$ has at least one subgroup different from $\{e\}$ and $G$.

Hope you'll help me. Thanks.

Comment: Do you know Sylow‘s theorem?

Comment: No.. we did not studied it yet..

Comment: Do you know Cauchy's lemma?

Comment: You can try to prove first that the order of $x$ must divide the order of $G$. Try a proof by contradiction.

Comment: yes.. order of x divide order of G .. so i think the possible values are pq and q and p .. 1 excluded .. isn't it ? what about the second question?

Comment: If $g\neq e$ has order $<pq$ then the cyclic group generated by $g$ works.  If it's order is $pq$ then $g^p$ has order $q$ and we can use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $g \in G \setminus \{1\}$. Consider $H = \langle g \rangle$, the subgroup generated by $g$. Recall (or prove) that $|H| = \operatorname{ord}(g)$. Since by Lagrange's theorem $|H|$ must divide $pq$, we have that $|H| \in \{p,q,pq\}$. Note that $|H|$ can't be $1$ precisely because $g \neq e$. Now, if $|H|$ is $p$ or $q$, this subgroup has less elements than $G$ and more than $\{e\}$. In particular, $H \neq G$ and $H \neq \{1\}$ which is what you want to prove.

The remaining case is when $H$ has order $pq$, where necessarily $H =G$ by a cardinality argument and so $H = G \simeq \mathbb{Z}_{pq}$ via $\phi: g^n \in G \mapsto n \in \mathbb{Z}_{pq}$ If this last step is not clear enough, prove that this is an injective morphism and recall that injections from sets of the same size are bijective. Finally, the group $\mathbb{Z}_{pq}$ has a proper nontrivial subgroup generated by $\langle p \rangle$, so by taking the preimage via $\phi$, we get a proper nontrivial subgroup $\phi^{-1}(\langle p \rangle)$.